# CCParticleSystemQuad emitter texture affects other emitters

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My cocos2d-iphone game has many CCParticleSystemQuad emitters around the scene. I created the .plist using Particle Creator mac app.

Anyway, currently I have 3 emitters using different .plist files. They all use the default user_particle.png image (which is not provided, so it is supposed to read from the "textureImageData" field to create the texture).

But then, I added one more emitter that uses a custom-made texture (my own .png file). But when I use it in the game, all other emitters begin using that texture, and not the other one. Why is that?

The way I am adding emitters:

```
    skyEmitter = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"Stuff.plist"];
    skyEmitter.positionType = kCCPositionTypeRelative;
    skyEmitter.position = ccp(player.position.x,player.position.y + 160);
    [map addChild:skyEmitter z:1000];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, I'm using particle designer by 71squared. I looked at my plist and the textureFileName field had the same names for each different emitter(I was having it embed the png too). I manually changed the names in the plist and the problem went away. Try changing the plist textureFileName field in your custom emitter to something unique.